# Combine values of multidimensional

Tags: php, jquery

So.. I have this array which is produced by serializeArray() from jquery passed to a php page..,

This is the output array i stored in $data in php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [value] => sample text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bdate
            [value] => sample date
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => addr
            [value] => sample addr
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => demo_des
            [value] => A
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => demo_des
            [value] => B
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => demo_des
            [value] => C
        )
)
```

and this is what id do:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){ //loop in $data
    if($data[$i][name]==$data[$i+1][name]||$data[$i][name]==$data[$i-1][name]){
        $impldval[] .= $data[$i][value];
        $impldkey[] .= $data[$i][name];
    }else{
        $arr[$data[$i][name]] .= $data[$i][value];
    }
}
```

basically I loop through data and check if data[num][name] is equal to next or previous, if it is then store it to an array and if not store it in different array..

Then I implode the duplicate values like this:

```
if(is_array($impldkey)&is_array($impldval)){$arr[$impldkey[0]] .= implode(',',$impldval);}
```

If we print $arr it will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => sample text
    [bdate] => sample date
    [addr] => sample addr
    [demo_des] => A,B,C
)
```

This is correct, but the problem is what if the array with same name is not in order meaning the increment to check will not work:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [value] => sample text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => demo_des
            [value] => A
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => addr
            [value] => sample addr
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => demo_des
            [value] => B
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => bdate
            [value] => sample date
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => demo_des
            [value] => C
        )
)
```

This will look like this because implode will also not work:

```
Array
(
    [name] => sample text
    [bdate] => sample date
    [addr] => sample addr
    [demo_des] => ABC
)
```

Im sorry if this has been asked before, but when I search all they ask is 2 or more arrays to merge..

Any suggestions? Or other work around this...

EDIT:
Ok this is what I need to do, I need to convert the multi-dimentional array from serializeArray() to a single array and combine duplicate names and implode the values, like the example above, I loop through the array and add them to "$arr" but if it has duplicate then I store it in different array then implode it and add to "$arr".

Comment: you need to explain the logic of data transformation, your description is vague and difficult to answer your question.

Comment: It's much easier to work with assigned arrays (key=>value) and than use an array_diff function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data =array (array('name'=>'name','value'=>'sample text'),array('name'=>'bdate','value'=>'sample date'),array('name'=>'addr','value'=>'sample addr'),array('name'=>'demo_des','value'=>'A'),array('name'=>'demo_des','value'=>'B'),array('name'=>'demo_des','value'=>'C')   );

foreach ($data as $k=>$v){

    $name=$v['name'];
    $value=$v['value'];

    if($out_put_array["$name"])
    { 
       $out_put_array["$name"].=','.$value;
    }
    else
    {
       $out_put_array["$name"]=$value;
    }

    }

print_r($out_put_array);
Array ( [name] => sample text [bdate] => sample date [addr] => sample addr [demo_des] => A,B,C )
```

Comment: Thanks for this! clean and simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayDefaults = array(
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '10',
    'c' => '10',
    'd' => '10',
    'e' => '10',
);

$arrayPost = array(
    array('name' =>'a', 'value'=>'1'),
    array('name' =>'b', 'value'=>'2'),
    array('name' =>'c', 'value'=>'3'),
    array('name' =>'d', 'value'=>'4'),
    array('name' =>'e', 'value'=>'5'),
    array('name' =>'f', 'value'=>'6')
);

$arrayNew = array();
foreach($arrayPost as $v){
    if(isset($v['name'], $v['value'])){
        //don't forget to sanitize values
        $value = filter_var($v['value'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        if(isset($arrayNew[$v['name']])){
            $arrayNew[$v['name']] .= ',' . $value;
        }else{
            $arrayNew[$v['name']] = $value;
        }
    }
}

//remove unknown keys
$arrayMatchKeys = array_intersect_key($arrayNew, $arrayDefaults);

//get only changed fields
$arrayUpdate = array_diff_assoc($arrayMatchKeys, $arrayDefaults);
```

result:

```
array (size=4)
  'b' => string '2' (length=1)
  'c' => string '3' (length=1)
  'd' => string '4' (length=1)
  'e' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In feature please use `var_export` for displaying array in question

```
$rowsGrouped = array();
$rows = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'first',
        'value' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'second',
        'value' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'first',
        'value' => 3
    ),
);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    if (isset($rowsGrouped[$name]) === false) {
        $rowsGrouped[$name] = $row;
    } else {
        $rowsGrouped[$name]['value'] .= sprintf(',%s', $row['value']);
    }
}
$rowsGrouped = array_values($rowsGrouped);
```